# how to check if blob column in mysql is null or empty

Tags: java, mysql

I'm using the next code to show image in label , to set nothing to label when picture column is null :

```
  ResultSet rset2 = stmnt.executeQuery("select Picture from Pictures where Client_ID_pass =1" );
                    while(rset2.next()){
                        byte[] Passimg = rset2.getBytes("Picture");
                        //Resize The ImageIcon
                    ImageIcon Passimage = new ImageIcon(Passimg);
                    Image Passim = Passimage.getImage();
                    Image PassmyImg = Passim.getScaledInstance(PassLBL.getWidth(), PassLBL.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                    ImageIcon newPassImage = new ImageIcon(PassmyImg);
                    PassLBL.setIcon(newPassImage);
```

```
                if(Passimg.length < 0){
PassLBL.settext("No Picture");                        
PassLBL.setIcon(null);
                }
                    }
```

I've tried the next :

if(Passimg.equals(null)
{PassLBL.settext("No Picture");}

and tried

if(Passimg == null)
{PassLBL.settext("No Picture"); }

but didn't work !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you retrive the data from the resultSet

```
 byte[] Passimg = rset2.getBytes("Picture");
```

put if statement there

```
if(passimg == null) {
   label.setText("nothing")
   lable.setIcon(null);//to remove the old picture 
}else {
//show the image like you did before
 lable.setText("");
 icon=create your icon here
 lable.setIcon(icon);
}
```

i didn't undertand what you need exactly hope this help you

Comment: this is exactly what i want ... I've substitute with the joptionpan for show passimg value ... I'll Edit the question text ... but it didn't work !

Comment: the problem in your code is that you showing the icon without testing the values

Comment: ok ... when i retrieve picture from database , it's being display on label, but when i change the record and this record don't have a picture it shows the past record picture .... so i need some way to display nothing when the column is null

Comment: call the setIcon(null) normaly this remove the image if not try to call label.repaint();  to remove the previous image   setIcon(null); setText("nothing");

Comment: this way worked when i use it in separated code ... but when i use right after my code it wont work

Comment: I've figure it out ... I just used PassLBL.setIcon(null) before all above code ... and it worked ... thank you for responding and help :)

Comment: you welcom omar by the way i'm charif from algeria you are from?!!

Comment: I'm omar from syria

Comment: thanks a lot, although it's been years since your reply
It was the thing i am looking for

Comment: @JafarZuabi yes It's been years I didn't write java code.  Thanks for the comment